# If $|A \cup B| = |A \cap B|$, is $A = B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This seems like it should be the case, but I can't find it written down anywhere. The only case I would be worried about is if there's some $x \neq y$ such that $x \in A \cup B$ and $y \in A \cap B$ that would give them the same size without equality. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For **finite** sets $A,B$, your statement is correct. That is because $A \cap B$ is a subset of $A \cup B$, and the equality of cardinals implies $A \cup B=A \cap B$. Then use
$$A \cap B \subset A,B \subset A \cup B$$
to get your claim.

For **infinite sets** your statement is wrong. For example $A= 2 \mathbb Z$ and $B= \mathbb Z$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Beat me to it. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the cardinality of the sets in your question - in that case, it's not true for infinite sets. Let A be the set of integers, B be the set of even integers, then both union and intersection of A and B are countable infinite but not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can write $A\cup B=A'\cup B'\cup (A\cap B)$, where the three sets are disjoint. If your sets are finite, then…

Otherwise…